# swift error self. used before super.init() call

Tags: ios, swift

I tried to use the `super.init` before initializing the objects and tried placing `self` in front of my objects. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

This is the code I currently have:

```
//
//  RecordController.swift
//  TuneUpV2
//
//  Created by Don Nijssen on 05-05-15.
//  Copyright (c) 2015 Don Nijssen. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class RecordController: NSObject {

    var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine
    var audioInputNode : AVAudioInputNode
    var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode
    var audioMixerNode: AVAudioMixerNode
    var audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer

    override init(){

        audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        audioInputNode = AVAudioInputNode()
        audioMixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()
        audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer()


        audioMixerNode = audioEngine.mainMixerNode

        let frameLength = UInt32(256)
        audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0), frameCapacity: frameLength)
        audioBuffer.frameLength = frameLength

        audioInputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

        audioInputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize:frameLength, format: audioInputNode.outputFormatForBus(0), block: {(buffer, time) in
            //let channels = UnsafeArray(start: buffer.floatChannelData, length: Int(buffer.format.channelCount))
            //let floats = UnsafeArray(start: channels[0], length: Int(buffer.frameLength))

            for var i = 0; i < Int(self.audioBuffer.frameLength); i+=Int(self.audioMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0).channelCount)
            {
                // doing my real time stuff
                //self.audioBuffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = floats[i];
                println(self.audioEngine.inputNode.rate);
            }
        })

        // setup audio engine
        audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)
        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioMixerNode, format: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0))

    }


    func start()
    {

        audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

        // play player and buffer
        audioPlayerNode.play()
        audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, atTime: nil, options: .Loops, completionHandler: nil)
    }

    func stop()
    {
        audioEngine.stop();
        audioPlayerNode.stop();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where exactly did you call `super.init()`?
This works in my playground:

```
override init(){

        audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
        audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
        audioInputNode = AVAudioInputNode()
        audioMixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()
        audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer()

        // Call super.init() immediately after all subclass properties are initialized
        super.init()

        audioMixerNode = audioEngine.mainMixerNode

        let frameLength = UInt32(256)
        audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0), frameCapacity: frameLength)
        audioBuffer.frameLength = frameLength

        audioInputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

        audioInputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize:frameLength, format: audioInputNode.outputFormatForBus(0), block: {(buffer, time) in
            //let channels = UnsafeArray(start: buffer.floatChannelData, length: Int(buffer.format.channelCount))
            //let floats = UnsafeArray(start: channels[0], length: Int(buffer.frameLength))

            for var i = 0; i < Int(self.audioBuffer.frameLength); i+=Int(self.audioMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0).channelCount)
            {
                // doing my real time stuff
                //self.audioBuffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = floats[i];
                println(self.audioEngine.inputNode.rate);
            }
        })

        // setup audio engine
        audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)
        audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioMixerNode, format: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0))

    }
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks a lot it helped! i called the super.init() right after the init()

Answer (score 0):

If your class is a subclass and you have non optional properties then you have to have give initial value to all properties. Since it is a sub class of NSObject and you are overriding the init method from its parent class you have to provide super.init() call before initialising properties.

```
class RecordController: NSObject {

var audioEngine: AVAudioEngine
var audioInputNode : AVAudioInputNode
var audioPlayerNode: AVAudioPlayerNode
var audioMixerNode: AVAudioMixerNode
var audioBuffer: AVAudioPCMBuffer

override init(){
    super.init()
    self.audioEngine = AVAudioEngine()
    self.audioPlayerNode = AVAudioPlayerNode()
    self.audioInputNode = AVAudioInputNode()
    self.audioMixerNode = AVAudioMixerNode()
    self.audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer()


    audioMixerNode = audioEngine.mainMixerNode

    let frameLength = UInt32(256)
    audioBuffer = AVAudioPCMBuffer(PCMFormat: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0), frameCapacity: frameLength)
    audioBuffer.frameLength = frameLength

    audioInputNode = audioEngine.inputNode

    audioInputNode.installTapOnBus(0, bufferSize:frameLength, format: audioInputNode.outputFormatForBus(0), block: {(buffer, time) in
        //let channels = UnsafeArray(start: buffer.floatChannelData, length: Int(buffer.format.channelCount))
        //let floats = UnsafeArray(start: channels[0], length: Int(buffer.frameLength))

        for var i = 0; i < Int(self.audioBuffer.frameLength); i+=Int(self.audioMixerNode.outputFormatForBus(0).channelCount)
        {
            // doing my real time stuff
            //self.audioBuffer.floatChannelData.memory[i] = floats[i];
            println(self.audioEngine.inputNode.rate);
        }
    })

    // setup audio engine
    audioEngine.attachNode(audioPlayerNode)
    audioEngine.connect(audioPlayerNode, to: audioMixerNode, format: audioPlayerNode.outputFormatForBus(0))

}


func start()
{

    audioEngine.startAndReturnError(nil)

    // play player and buffer
    audioPlayerNode.play()
    audioPlayerNode.scheduleBuffer(audioBuffer, atTime: nil, options: .Loops, completionHandler: nil)
}

func stop()
{
    audioEngine.stop();
    audioPlayerNode.stop();
}
```

}

As per Apple documentation.